# Transformer Inverter vs Inductor Inverter

Tags: transformer, inductor

I want to make a 50 kW inverter for a solar power application. 
The maximum solar DC voltage is 1 kV.   And the output of the inverter will be 230 V AC.

Now I can built it in two ways, using transformer or inductors.

What I want to know is what is the best solution for it?
And what is the difference in between transformer inverter and inductor base inverter?

Comment: So your input voltage is 1,000,000 Volts...

Comment: 1KV , Typing Mistake

Comment: 1 kV, 50 kW ....

Comment: Yes 1KV DC  input... 230 volt AC Output.. 50 KW

Comment: I am going to politely ask...what are your qualifications and skill sets needed to build a 50 KW power supply that must do several things exactly the right way?

Comment: Presumably you are talking about a 3 phase output with a line voltage of 398 volts i.e. 42 amps load per phase?

Comment: Yes, I was just correcting your correction. K is kelvin, k is 1000

Comment: @Sparky256 Engineering in Electronics. And i am not alone , i have a full team. I just wanted to know the difference in between.

Comment: @Andyaka Yes My Output is 3 Phase. Can you tell me the difference between Transformer and Inductor based Inverter Design ??

Comment: @Chu Sorry My bad. My Output Watt is 50kW .

Comment: Presumably you heard about these terms somewhere so if you can link to that document then it will all become clear @EhsanHabib.

Comment: @Andyaka  No i did not heard anything. I see a Local company Designing a 50kW Transformer based inverter. And a Chinese Company is also making a 50kW Inverter. The only difference i found is the SIZE in beetween them. Transformer one is large and bulky. Where the Inductor based one is Light weight & Small compared to the transformer one.

Comment: This is a question that needs to be solved by someone familiar with specific requirements of your output, ie, you may need a grid tie inverter.  It does not appear to be an electronic design question and it is far beyond the scope of a stack exchange question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably you are talking about a 3 phase output with a line voltage of 398 volts i.e. 42 amps load per phase?

> Yes My Output is 3 Phase.

To create line voltages of 398 volts requires a DC bus rail that can handle the full peak to peak sinewave limits. So 398 volts RMS requires a bus rail that is 398 x \$\sqrt2\$ x 2 volts = 1126 volts. Then there will be some volt drop across the transistors so you would aim to have a DC bus voltage of something closer to 1200 volts.

> The Maximum Solar Dc volt is 1 KV

If 1 kV is the maximum and normal running might be expected at (say) 40% of this value (400 volts BUS) then you would require output transformers to raise the AC voltage you have produced to something like 398 volts.

A transformer on its own will not give you an inverter function if you are using PWM to control the wave-forms; you will still inductors to act as energy storage devices to smooth out the 3 wave forms to be approximately sinusoidal in nature.

The transformer can be made to act as both a 3-phase transformer AND inductor but it will be bigger than just 3 inductors so this probably explains the size difference between the two devices you commented on.

Given what you have revealed, it seems likely you will need a transformer. Bear also in mind that this is a question and answer site and not a forum so, trying to leverage extra answers based on maybe "this" or maybe "that" will not be indefinitely tolerated. Neither is this site a design house.

Answer (score 1):

The size of an inverter does not depend on transformer vs. inductor but mainly on projected lifetime, losses and heat removal, and maintainablitity.

Given the output power is identical:

- A small device typically has more losses and produces more heat.
- A device producing more heat has less lifetime.
- A small device typically is not maintenance-friendly.

There may be a difference in the technology involved of course. But even then …

For example consider the difference between a modern inverter based welding supply and a 50Hz transformer based welding supply:

The inverter based welding supply

- has better current regulation and nice features as high-voltage ignition and anti-stick protection.
- has lot of parts which may fail if overheated, it has a fan which blows dirt into it, and repair is useless.

In contrary, the 50Hz transformer based welding supply

- is nearly immune to overheating and still works when it's in a pile of dirt. If it fails, a half-assed electrician (a blacksmith in reality) can repair it.
- current regulation is subpar. No extra features.

**Both may be a good fit for your application.**